# Broadcasting with a condition

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider the code shown below. It produces `a` having `shape (1, 4, 2, 2)`,   `b` having `shape (4, 1, 2, 2)`,   and `c` which broadcasts to an array having `shape (4, 4, 2, 2)`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(4, 2, 2))   
b = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(4, 2, 2))

a = a[np.newaxis, :]
b = b[:, np.newaxis]

c = a+b
```

**QUESTION:** As written, `c` holds **16**   2x2 arrays.  But, I only want the **6**   2x2 arrays that are formed when `a`'s index along `axis=1` is **greater** than  `b`'s index along `axis=0`.  These would be held in a 3d array for `shape (6, 2, 2)`.  How can this be done?

(the  2x2 array counts for the **greater**,  **less**,  and  **equal** cases would be 6 + 6 + 4 = 16, the cases that my code snippet currently produces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.  Shapes are right, I'll let you verify the numbers.

```
In [225]: a,b
Out[225]: 
(array([[[5, 2],
         [4, 0]],
 
        [[4, 2],
         [3, 1]],
 
        [[2, 9],
         [0, 2]],
 
        [[3, 6],
         [1, 6]]]),
 array([[[4, 9],
         [4, 4]],
 
        [[1, 5],
         [6, 3]],
 
        [[8, 2],
         [3, 2]],
 
        [[6, 3],
         [9, 2]]]))
```

the 6 lower tri indices:

```
In [226]: I,J = np.tril_indices(4,-1); I,J
Out[226]: (array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]))
```

Advanced indexing:

```
In [227]: a[I,:,:]+b[J,:,:]
Out[227]: 
array([[[ 8, 11],
        [ 7,  5]],

       [[ 6, 18],
        [ 4,  6]],

       [[ 3, 14],
        [ 6,  5]],

       [[ 7, 15],
        [ 5, 10]],

       [[ 4, 11],
        [ 7,  9]],

       [[11,  8],
        [ 4,  8]]])
```